# React push to state on submit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I am trying to push to my react state every time a submit my form, but after 2 values stored the state start to get overwriten. Function code:

```
  function addOrder(values: any) {
    let ordersArray: any[] = [];
    ordersArray.push({
      id: uuidv4(),
      client: clientsField?.label,
      catalog: catalogField?.label,
      product: productField.label,
      regularPrice: Number(productField.regularPrice),
      discountPrice: Number(productField.discountPrice),
      amount: values.amount,
      totalValue: values.amount * Number(productField.regularPrice),
    });
    setPedido(pedidosArray);
  }
```

update: I can submit the form but my state is still getting overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this there is no need to an extra array:

```
  function adcionarPedido(values: any) {
    let pedidosArray = [...pedidos];
    pedidosArray.push({
      id: uuidv4(),
      cliente: clientesField?.label,
      catalogo: catalogoField?.label,
      produto: produtoField.label,
      valorRegular: Number(produtoField.valorRegular),
      valorOferta: Number(produtoField.valorOferta),
      quantidade: values.quantidade,
      valorBruto: values.quantidade * Number(produtoField.valorRegular),
    });
    setPedido(pedidosArray);
  }
```

Comment: I got this error when trying to submit my form: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: pedidos is not iterable

Comment: is pedidos an object or an array?

Comment: It is an array of objects

Comment: I tweaked my code a little and now your solution is working. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know why it doesn`t work, but this is the **proper way** how to do it:

```
  const [pedidosArray, setPedidosArray] = useState<any[]>();

  function adcionarPedido(values: any) {
    setPedidosArray((currentStateOfPediosArray) => 
     [...currentStateOfPediosArray, {
     id: uuidv4(),
     cliente: clientesField?.label,
     catalogo: catalogoField?.label,
     produto: produtoField.label,
     valorRegular: Number(produtoField.valorRegular),
     valorOferta: Number(produtoField.valorOferta),
     quantidade: values.quantidade,
     valorBruto: values.quantidade * Number(produtoField.valorRegular)
     })  
  };
```

Comment: I got this error: Argument of type '(currentStateOfPediosArray: any[] | undefined) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<any[] | undefined>'. and also there are some little syntax errorss in your code

Comment: I just edited it, this should work